# Trying to formulate optimization problems as a linear program (LP) or a quadratic program (QP)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I'm trying to formulate and determine the variables, objective, and constraints for the minimization problem $\min_\vec{x}f(\vec{x})$ for the following functions $f \in$ ($q,r,s,t$) as linear program (LP) or quadratic program (QP) or neither (N):

Where $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $|\vec{v}|_p$ is the $p$-norm.

$$\displaystyle \\
q(\vec{x}) = |A\vec{x}-\vec{y}|_∞ + |\vec{x}|_1 \\
r(\vec{x}) = |A\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2_2 + |\vec{x}|_1 \\
s(\vec{x}) = |A\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2_2 - |\vec{x}|_1 \\
t(\vec{x}) = |A\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2_2 + |\vec{x}|_1^2 \\
$$

My best guess right now is $q$ is LP, $r$ is QP, $s$ is N, and $t$ is QP.

Comment: you are correct

Comment: @LinAlg but i'm not sure how to properly justify it or how to articulate what the variables, objective, and constraints are.

could you help?

Comment: you should be able to reformulate $q,r,t$ (2-norm-squared is straightforward, the others require auxiliary variables, also straightforward). Note that $s$ is not convex, and it is not likely that a convex reformulation is possible.

Comment: @LinAlg it's not exactly straightforward to me.

could you please be more explicit ?

Comment: minimizing $|z|_{\infty}$ is same as minimizing scalar $\alpha$ subject to $-\alpha \leq z \leq \alpha$. Similarily, you should have seen a similar reformulation for the 1-norm, and using these auxilliary epigraph variables will work in three convex cases.